# Git commits via command-line fail, showing > symbol

Tags: macos, git, bash, command-line

I'm new to bash. After I've staged files to my local git repository and typed in the commands to commit:

```
    git commit -m "Descriptive message"
```

Git (or is it terminal?) stops dead, showing the

```
    >
```

symbol. It won't accept further commands and I have to exit the session and start a new one. Why does this happen?

Comment: Does your message contain double quotes?

Comment: Yes, it does :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use quotes or some other special bash character inside your commit message? Be sure that it is a well-formed string. Try using apostrophes around the message.

The > means bash is waiting for another line of input, so you probably didn't close the commit message properly.

If still stuck, please post the exact command you are using.

Comment: It was indeed double quotes in my string making the command fail. Thank you for explaining the meaning of the > symbol. I will now go learn about escaping characters in bash strings.

Comment: Look for `PS2` in the bash manual.